# HTTP 1.1でChunked transfer encodingを拒否する方法

Tags: http

とある組み込みマイコン向けのHTTPライブラリで難儀しています。
ライブラリにgetという関数があり、これを実行すると指定したURLにHTTP 1.1でGETを発行して、応答の本文を文字列として返してくるのですが、
サーバーがChunked transfer encodingで応答すると（即ち、応答ヘッダに Transfer-Encoding: Chunked が含まれた状態）、これをデコードせずに生の文字列を返してしまうのです。

応答ヘッダを取得することはできないので、プログラム側でチャンクをデコードすることはできません。（チャンク化されているかどうかを一意に判別できないため）
また、TCPやHTTPを含めた一切の通信処理は、完全に独立したMCU内で処理されるため、自分でsocketを使ってHTTPを実装することもできません。「

但し、get関数の引数として、要求ヘッダに１行だけ任意のヘッダを追加できる機能があるので、これを利用して、サーバーに、チャンク化しないように要求できないかと考えているのですが・・・
何か方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: [RFC-7230(HTTP/1.1の仕様)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-4.1)を見る限り、 _A recipient MUST be able to parse and decode the chunked transfer coding._ とありますから、「受信側がchunkedを解釈できないのはHTTP/1.1では許されない」(つまりそのHTTPライブラリは「HTTP/1.1対応」とは言えない)と言うことになります。HTTP/1.1仕様を普通に実装するサーバであれば、要求ヘッダの内容は一切考慮せず、Content-Lengthがすぐに決定できない場合にはchunked transfer encodingを使用します。つまり、ご記載のような動作をするライブラリでは「任意のHTTP/1.1サーバとの通信は無理」と結論せざるを得ません。「通信相手をchunkedを使用しない特殊なサーバに限定する」かまたは(そのライブラリが対応していれば)「HTTP/1.0を使用する」しかないように思われます。そのライブラリではHTTP/1.0は使用可能なのでしょうか?

Comment: OOPer様、ご回答ありがとうございます。はい、HTTP 1.1でChunked transfer encodingは対応が必須だということは知っていたのですが、プロトコル上で回避する方法はないようですね。HTTP 1.0に切り替えることはできないので、サーバーサイドで対応する方法しかないようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOPerさんのコメントにあるようにHTTP/1.1において`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`への対応は必須ですので、未対応ということは不正なクライアントであるとしか言いようがありません。
補足をしておくと、HTTP/1.0ではコンテンツ長が不明な場合、コネクション切断をもってコンテンツの終端を表していましたが、これでは異常終了と区別できません。HTTP/1.1で`chunked`が導入され必須となっているのもコンテンツ長が不明なコンテンツを正確に扱うためです。

> get関数の引数として、要求ヘッダに１行だけ任意のヘッダを追加できる機能があるので、これを利用して、サーバーに、チャンク化しないように要求できないか

[TEヘッダー](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.3)を用いることでクライアント側が解釈可能な`Transfer-Encoding`を事前通知することができます。この機能が正攻法ではありますが、既に説明しているように`chunked`は必須なためこれを拒否するようなリクエストは認められていません。

期待通りの動作をするか確実ではありませんが、WebサーバーApacheのデフォルト設定には[おかしな挙動をするクライアントに対してプロトコルの動作を変更する](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#examples)というものがあります。設定内容としては

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
```

等があります。これを逆手にとって、`User-Agent: MSIE 4.0b2;`等を送信することで、Webサーバーに対してHTTP/1.0で応答するように求めることができるかもしれません。HTTP/1.0であれば`chunked`は存在しませんので`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`が返されることはないはずです。
（WebサーバーがApacheとは限りませんが、おかしな挙動をするクライアント対策が施されていることを期待してということです。）

Comment: sayuri様、ご回答ありがとうございます。試しに空のTEヘッダを付けてみましたが、やはり、chunkedされてしまいました。Apache側の設定で強制的にHTTP 1.0に変更できるとのこと、情報ありがとうございます。必ずしも任意のサーバーを相手に通信する必要はないので、通信したい相手のサーバーがchunkedを不可避なら、このような回避策を考えるしかなさそうですね。